# tmux is not using screen-256color even it is set in the config file

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux

I am trying to get tmux to use screen-256color instead of xterm-256color, as it is not recommended. But when I am not using tmux, I would like to keep it as xterm-256color

A little bit of my setup, I am currently using iTerm2 and ssh to my development linux box, which is using zsh.

In my ~/.zshrc, I have:

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

In my ~/.tmux.conf, I have:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

With this configuraiton, without tmux, echo $TERM returns xterm-256color (which is right) and with tmux, echo $TERM is still returning xterm-256color instead of screen-256color.

Is there anything else I need to set in order for this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: xterm-256color (typo mistake?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your `.zshrc` file to check if you are running in tmux:

```
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason this does not work as expected is, that the `zsh` session that is started inside `tmux` overwrites `TERM`.

You should not set `TERM` from within in your shell. `TERM` is the way the terminal informs the shell and other applications about its capabilities (number of colors, key sequences for special keys, etc.). If you change `TERM` inside the shell, you change the what features the shell and applications expect from the terminal without the terminal itself knowing about it. Oftentimes this may not be an actual issue, but it is better to change the terminal configuration and set the desired value there.

You already did so when setting `screen-256color` in the configuration of `tmux`, which is essentially a terminal emulator, too. To do it for `iTerm2` (tested with version 3.0.10):

1. Open the *Preferences* dialog (in the Menu: *iTerm2* → *Preferences*, or press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).
2. In the dialog go to *Profiles* → *Terminal*.
3. There you can choose the desired value for `TERM` under *Report Terminal Type*.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. We should not set `TERM` inside `.zshrc` file. Or the `TERM` inside Tmux will also be `xterm-256color`.